# TFT Buttons on SainSmart 3.2" LCD

Tags: gpio, touchscreen, pitft

Has anyone gotten the buttons to work on the SainSmart 3.2" TFT screens for Raspberry Pi? I have some ideas to make them call commands or Python scripts, but don't have any documentation from SainSmart as to how they work, such as which GPIO pins they are mapped to. I suppose I could experiment and find out, but that's why I'm asking the forum first.

- Raspberry Pi 2
- SainSmart 3.2" TFT LCD Module 320*240 Touch Screen Display for Raspberry Pi
  SKU:20-111-971

We can see the buttons on the right side of the module here. [image: SainSmart 3.2" TFT LCD Module for Raspberry Pi]

Idea--what if I just ran `./pintest` on this after hitting a few buttons? After all, it's plugged right into the GPIOs.

Comment: People like to help, but they like to be helped to help.  I can't be bothered to search for the specifications of the unit you are talking about.  You really ought to provide relevant links.

Answer (score 1):

very interesting development. These buttons do indeed push to GPIO pins, and only when pressed. So, GPIO 11/SCLK is the TFT button labeled "K1"--think I will map to this.